# How to call a variable from a statistical method C#

Tags: c#, .net

How to print the new String variable in the main method?

```
public static void ReverseString( char[] charArray)   
{
    int i = charArray.Length - 1, j = 0;
    while (j < i)
    {
        if (!char.IsLetter(charArray[j]))
            j++;
        else if (!char.IsLetter(charArray[i]))
            i--;
        else
        {
            char tmp = charArray[j];
            charArray[j] = charArray[i];
            charArray[i] = tmp;
            j++;
            i--;
            
        }
        string newString = string.Concat(charArray);
    }
}
```

```
public static class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the string" );
    }
}
```

I'm new to programming.

Comment: `return newString`

Comment: @Charlieface: Not quite.  I don't think the OP knows how to make a method call.

Comment: I strongly suggest looking up online C# tutorials. What you're asking about is C# 101. There are several parts missing to get this (reading input, passing input to methods, returning output to methods), ... and this answer would have to be much too broad and lengthy for StackOverflow. A tutorial will actually explain this better to you than a StackOverflow answer will.

Comment: public static class Anagram
    {
        public static IEnumerator SplitString()
        {
            string inputWords = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] myWords = inputWords.Split(" ");
            foreach (string word in myWords)
            {
                char[] charArray = word.ToCharArray();
                yield return charArray;
            }
        }

Comment: my first method

Comment: Your code with some corrections https://ideone.com/PS7YRb

Answer (score 1):

Change your metods to:

```
public static string ReverseString(string sentence)   
{
var charArr = sentence.ToCharArray(); 
... your code
return string.Concat(charArray);
}
....
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine( ReverseString( "Enter the string" ));
    }
```

Comment: Do I have to change my methods ? I only need to print the result of the reversestring method to the main method. I do not know how to do this .

Comment: `"Enter the string"` is clearly not intended to be the input string.

Comment: I don't want to add ReadLine() since I hope @ItachiU knows this at least.

Comment: @ItachiU Why repeat the question when it has already been answered? If you struggle with reading the code in the given answer, that's just more incentive for you to actually look up a tutorial instead of brute force your understanding playing 20 questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Flater Thanks for the comment I'll take all comments into account

Comment: And he can remove the `string newString = string.Concat(charArray);`